# Collpitts oscillator signal distorted

Tags: oscillator, crystal, common-collector

I am trying to build a Collpitts oscillator using an 8MHz crystal, but the signal I get, is completely distorted. Any idea why?

The yellow signal is probed at the output, while the pink is probing the base of the BJT.

To start with I thought the problem was that my BJT was not in linear region, so I increased the load resistor to 2k to reduce the amplitude of the input signal, but the distortion was still there.

Do I have some secondary oscillation somewhere? Any idea how to fix it?

PS: The crystal is 8MHz not 8mhz.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not enough gain there

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 sorry, I am completely newbie. Gain where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change R3 from 100k to 68k
Change R2 from 147k to 27k thus Rb=20k and Rin= 100k hFE*Re ~100 * 1k
Replace wire with 1k from emitter to C2//C3 to match R1.

Root Cause:  The C loading Re at some harmonic of 8MHz is causing output distortion.  When there is series C coupling on Emitter always make Rmin load >= Re.  In this case equal.

Expect 2Vpp sine output.  Use another buffer if you plan on driving any significant capacitance ( e.g 30 pf /ft)

Comment: Put your fingers in your ears, close your eyes, and ship it!

Comment: The base signal is fine but the emitter signal was distorted because the 5th harmonic via caps were loading the emitter on AC more than the DC bias current, which always causes distortion. Harmonic distortion, jitter or phase noise  is often given a design spec.

Comment: Are you some kind of wizard or something? Worked like a charm!:)

Comment: You too can become a wizard when you fix as many failures as I have.  The last item is the cause for distortion, the 1s two increase current to be less dependent on hFE. Take any Common Emitter Rc and load it with a smaller R AC coupled and it becomes DC current starved and thus distorted AC signal.